# Sliding screen door options without kit

Tags: doors, door-frame, sliding-glass-door, screens

I’m trying to determine a good option for a sliding screen door for a patio French door.

So far what I’ve seen are mostly kit options, but they’re pricey and I can’t quite tell if they’d work for our door. It also seems many are retractable which I’d prefer to avoid since we have cats that may try to push through the screens.

What I’m wondering is if it’s possible/easy to just buy separate doors and tracks and install custom? I’m quite handy and can figure out details, but could use recommendations on what kind of tracks and doors to look for.

I’m imagining a dual track that can fit 2 doors that can both slide (like sliding shower doors) and in a perfect world it would be possible to remove the doors if we ever needed to move something large—though this would be very rare.

The size of the door is pretty standard, about 71-3/8” x 80” inside the door jamb right at the outside trim. The saddle is slightly downward sloped. This area is covered by a roof so no worries about rain if there was a need to drill down into the saddle.

Any advice or experiences would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Possible? Perhaps. Easy? I have to doubt it - the reason you see "kits and not parts" is that there's no meaningful standardization of parts, so the way you get parts that work together is as a kit.

Comment: one of the reasons they are expensive is counter balancing and mechanism to keep them "shut" (often magnets).

Comment: @MrR can you explain how counterbalancing comes into play? I would have guessed with a top and bottom track, a latch to keep the doors shut (like a pocket door has) and maybe some sort of brush seal or weather strip to close the gap between the two sliding doors—what else should really be needed?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I can understand that, different brands having different fits. Do you know of any modular system with doors and tracks that can be put together as needed? The kits look decent but most I can find are retractable (also I’m trying to find brown or black, which makes this all the more impossible.)

Comment: Ah - sorry - wrong application .. the system i have is retractable and the system keeps tension tight on the screen - regardless of how much is pulled out - but the force to open is the same - regardless of how much is pulled out (it covers 6 panes of doors / windows).

Comment: Best bet (and it's not a great bet) would be to find a salvage sliding glass door for the frames and tracks. It's not a great bet because they are the sort of "too large and awkward thing" that ends up broken in a dumpster rather than hauled away to salvage, more often than not. They typically have one cheesy screen and two glass panels. By the time it hits salvage the screen is probably useless, but the (sturdier) glass frames could be refit to screens since you want a pair. Or you just build the whole thing custom. And no, I do NOT know of any "modular system" for this.